# Mariadb using IF in trigger to fill null value on insert

Tags: mariadb, trigger, condition

Trying to use a trigger to a) fill in a new column `top_category` with values left of a colon, found in `category`, then b) If there is no colon, then put entire insert value into `top_category`. I can't get this second trigger structured to create.

https://dbfiddle.uk/jwLle13e

```
CREATE TABLE qn_txs (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  category VARCHAR(250),
  top_category VARCHAR(250)
);

-- Stage 1 trigger works
--  CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_top_category1` BEFORE INSERT ON `qn_txs` 
--    FOR EACH ROW 
--  SET NEW.`top_category` = LEFT(NEW.category, INSTR(NEW.category, ":") - 1);

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_top_category2` BEFORE INSERT ON `qn_txs` 
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
         SET NEW.`top_category` = LEFT(NEW.category, INSTR(NEW.category, ":") - 1)
         -- make sure top_category is not null if there is a value in category
            IF (NEW.`top_category` = '')
             THEN
              SET NEW.`top_category` = NEW.`category`;
           END IF;
END//

DELIMITER;

INSERT INTO qn_txs (category)
VALUES ('I should also be a top cat'), ('bananas:green'), ('baseball:table'), (''), ('Very long string: with spaces');

SELECT * FROM qn_txs;
```

Here's a table of the desired output after the insert is complete.

| id | category | top_category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I should also be a top cat | I should also be a top cat |
| 2 | bananas:green | bananas |
| 3 | baseball:table | baseball |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 | Very long string: with spaces | Very long string |

Comment: For the first VALUE, you want that phrase in `category` also?  Show us thedelivered result and the desired result after the `INSERT`.

Comment: Here's another attempt at the trigger, but it still fails to create and errors are not helpful :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_top_category` BEFORE INSERT ON `qn_txs`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF(INSTR(NEW.category, ":") = 0) THEN
   SET NEW.`top_category` = NEW.`category`;
  ELSE  
 SET NEW.`top_category` = LEFT(NEW.category, INSTR(NEW.category, ":") - 1);
  END IF;
 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `t_add_top_category2` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `qn_txs` 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.top_category = SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.category, ':', 1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/_ru7qse3

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!